# Scriban Template Engine Multi loop Supports

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, template-engine, scriban

I am trying to use Scriban Template Engine for multiple loop support.
For Example

```
string bodyTextSub = "{{ for service in services }} ServiceName: {{ service }} {{ end }}" +
                "{{ for subservice in subServiceList }} SubServiceName: {{ subservice }} {{ end }}";
List<string> subServiceList = new List<string>
            {
                "PingSubService",
                "UrlSubService"
            };
            Dictionary<string, List<string>> serviceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
            {
                {"emailContent", subServiceList},
                {"mailContent", subServiceList}
            };

            var template2 = Template.Parse(bodyTextSub);
            var result2 = template2.Render(new { services = serviceDictionary });
            Console.WriteLine(result2.ToString());
```

I am getting the output like

```
ServiceName: {key: emailContent, value: [PingSubService, UrlSubService]}
```

I want that based on the key we should loop in the subservices but it is not happening.
Can anyone help me in this ?

My second question does Scriban Template Engine Supports nested looping ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have not received any reply yet from anyone.
No one used Scriban Template Engine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scriban does support nested looping.  I've updated your code to show how you would do this.  I've updated the code and the results per your request.

```
var bodyTextSub = @"{{ for service in services }} 
ServiceName: {{ service.key }} {{$counter = 1}}
SubServices: {{ for subService in service.value }}{{ `
  `; $counter + `. `; $counter = $counter + 1 ; }}{{ subService }}{{ end }}
{{ end }}";
var subServiceList = new List<string>
{
    "PingSubService",
    "UrlSubService"
};
var serviceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
{
    {"emailContent", subServiceList},
    {"mailContent", subServiceList}
};

var template2 = Template.Parse(bodyTextSub);
var result2 = template2.Render(new {services = serviceDictionary});
Console.WriteLine(result2.ToString());
```

This will result in the following output:

```
ServiceName: emailContent 
SubServices: 
  1. PingSubService
  2. UrlSubService
 
ServiceName: mailContent 
SubServices: 
  1. PingSubService
  2. UrlSubService
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable input.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply. I was on holiday.
I have just one more question regarding the above reply.
Currently, for the one or more sub-services we are separating by the commas,
Can you please give example or modify the code so instead of comma we will print in a new line with a number. For Example
1.PingSubService
2.UrlSubService and so on.
Thanks